# Deploy a PR to Prod

Tags: docker, jenkins, github-actions, spinner, datadog

I did a deployment for a PR which was several commits behind master to production(as I did not want to take a particular feature to prod). The deployment was successful and I could see the the correct deployment in datadog as well. However on testing we found that the feature which was not even a part of this branch got deployed. On further investigation we observed that the branch and commit were correct and it did not have that piece of code, the docker image was successfully generated. Can someone please help me understand the possible root cause of this issue? Also, since this resulted in error I want to understand what is the best suggested approach to move specific changes to prod and not all the changes which are part of master?

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to say exactly where the problem is. For starters, have you verified that the commit that was released doesn't have any code that was not supposed to be in it? There might have been some unforeseen changes when you did a merge across branches. If you can see for a fact that the specific commit only has the necessary changes, then it's probably an issue that happened during release. Check your release pipeline for any inconsistencies. Perhaps you pulled one branch and released another one?

Generally, you would tag your releases so that you have a good idea up to which commit got released. You could also have a separate release branch where you can merge in the master up to the point you want to release as well as cherry pick any commits that you want to go into the release. You can also make sure that the commit/release branch doesn't have any unnecessary code manually before releasing.